# How to update multiple objects embedded in an array across multiple documents in MongoDB using MongoDB query language?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these **2** documents in my '**resources**' collection -

```
db.resources.insertMany([
{
Name: "Mark",
Gender: "M",
State: "VA",
TeamRoles: 
    [
     {
        Team: "A",
        Role: "Quality Advisor",
        Active: true
     },
     {
        Team: "B",
        Role: "Systems Analyst",
        Active: true
     }
     ]

},
{
Name: "Stacy",
Gender: "F",
State: "GA",
TeamRoles: 
    [
     {
        Team: "A",
        Role: "Systems Analyst",
        Active: true
     },
     {
        Team: "B",
        Role: "Developer",
        Active: true
     }
     ]
}])
```

Here, I want to update the role from '**Systems Analyst**' to '**Business Analyst**' for all the matching objects in the *TeamRoles* array across all the documents in the resources collection.
Is there a way to achieve this using the Mongo DB query language (not JavaScript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {'TeamRoles.Role': "Systems Analyst"},
   { $set: { "TeamRoles.$[element].Role" : "Business Analyst" } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "element.Role": "Systems Analyst" } ] }
)
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2776c7dc791f82e7e1736d"),
    "Name" : "Mark",
    "Gender" : "M",
    "State" : "VA",
    "TeamRoles" : [ 
        {
            "Team" : "A",
            "Role" : "Quality Advisor",
            "Active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "Team" : "B",
            "Role" : "Systems Analyst",
            "Active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "Team" : "C",
            "Role" : "Systems Analyst",
            "Active" : true
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2776c7dc791f82e7e1736e"),
    "Name" : "Stacy",
    "Gender" : "F",
    "State" : "GA",
    "TeamRoles" : [ 
        {
            "Team" : "A",
            "Role" : "Systems Analyst",
            "Active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "Team" : "B",
            "Role" : "Developer",
            "Active" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2776c7dc791f82e7e1736d"),
    "Name" : "Mark",
    "Gender" : "M",
    "State" : "VA",
    "TeamRoles" : [ 
        {
            "Team" : "A",
            "Role" : "Quality Advisor",
            "Active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "Team" : "B",
            "Role" : "Business Analyst",
            "Active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "Team" : "C",
            "Role" : "Business Analyst",
            "Active" : true
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2776c7dc791f82e7e1736e"),
    "Name" : "Stacy",
    "Gender" : "F",
    "State" : "GA",
    "TeamRoles" : [ 
        {
            "Team" : "A",
            "Role" : "Business Analyst",
            "Active" : true
        }, 
        {
            "Team" : "B",
            "Role" : "Developer",
            "Active" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

**Ref :** [updateMany-arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#examples)